# Desktop refreshed when FileDialog is opened

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Actually in my winform app i have a button which open a `FileDialog` which permise the user to choose a file.

The issue (?) is that when it's called for the first time the desktop seems to be refreshed and i can't get if it's a normal behavior or not.

Here is an example of what is happening (look at the icons on the desktop)

[image]

Here is the method called by the button

```
Private Sub Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpload.Click
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Seleziona file.."
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    fd.Filter = "File Excel|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It may happen. But, what is `OpenFileDialog`, here? `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()` or `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();`? Where/when are you showing it? Maybe post your actual code.

Comment: @Jimi it's System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog and actually it's yet my actual code i just truncated a part where i make some controlls ok "OK" click of the dialog it's inside a click handler if you can notice

Comment: OpenFileDialog derives from [FileDialog](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,41), which derives from [CommonDialog](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/CommonDialog.cs). If you follow the sequence of method calls, you can see it performs a series of operations that interact with the desktop. Among these, it [activates the Themes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/CommonDialog.cs,307), (...),

Comment: tests the Screen position of the Owner etc. If you have active custom Themes or other shell extensions, these extensions get activated in a way or another. This causes cascading events, all related to the Desktop and the Shell. Refreshing the current Shell cache is one of those events. So, you can see the isons on the Desktop *blink* (similar to what happens when an installer creates a desktop icon). Anyway, you should post your complete code when asking quesions about its behaviour. There might be something else going on there that slows down a procedure for some reason. Hooks, for example.

Comment: @Jimi oh as i'm using Metro Framework should this cause cascading events as it have to load some dll's?

Comment: Yes, it does. That framework has a lot of flaws, btw.

Comment: @Jimi yeah actually tested without the framework and it doesn't refresh the icons, thank you